# LINQ Distinct Query

Tags: c#, linq

I have a C# application that loads a List of CLR objects called "Tasks". Each Task has the following properties:

```
public int ID { get; set; }
public int TypeID { get; set; }
public string TypeName { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
```

I am trying to find the unique types of tasks in this list. I thought I would try to use LINQ to do it. However, I cannot figure out how to do it. How do I say give me all of the unique TypeID and TypeName in this list? Currently I'm trying the following which is getting me no where. In fact, it wound even compile.

```
var uniqueTasks = allTasks.Distinct(p => p.TypeID);
```

Thank you,

Comment: Do you want the distinct tasks or the distinct types?

Comment: Do you want a list of distinct TypeIDs and a list of distinct TypeNames or a list of distinct pairs TypeID, TypeName?

Answer (score 6):

Let me make sure I understand the problem: you have a sequence of tasks called allTasks, and you would like a sequence *without duplicates* of all the ids, yes?

Transform the sequence of tasks into a sequence of ids:

```
var ids = allTasks.Select(p=>p.TypeId);
```

Now you have a sequence of ids.  You wish to filter out the duplicates from that sequence:

```
var distinctIds = ids.Distinct();
```

And you're done. Is that what you were after?

Comment: That's a cool way to do it. But your `var ids` or `var distinctIds` is a list of `int`. not the original list of `objects` called `Task`. What if I want to use some other thing from `Task` like `TypeName`? I need to query the org list again to grab the necessary info.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to do this is to use [`GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx):

```
var uniqueTasks = allTasks.GroupBy(p => p.TypeID);
```

This will give you a set of groupings that map a `TypeID` to the tasks with that ID.

If you want a set of tasks, you can write

```
var uniqueTasks = allTasks.GroupBy(p => p.TypeID).Select(g => g.First());
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement your own comparer:

```
public class TaskComparer : IEqualityComparer<Task>
{

    #region IEqualityComparer<Task> Members

    public bool Equals(Task x, Task y)
    {
        return x.TypeID == y.TypeID && x.TypeName == y.TypeName;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Task obj)
    {
        return obj.TypeID.GetHashCode() + obj.TypeName.GetHashCode();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
var uniqueTasks = allTasks.Distinct(new TaskComparer());
```

**EDIT:** Hacked out some GetHashCode() thanks to Slaks who pointed out that GetHashCode is absolutely necessary (I guess it builds a HashTable internally)

Comment: WRONG WRONG WRONG!  **You _MUST_ implement `GetHashCode`!**

Comment: Because otherwise, it will be completely useless.

Comment: um... When is the Hash code *of the comparer* going to be important?

Comment: @James: Love the sarcasm. However, it's not so far fetched to think that it calls the equals method to compare to items. I know now that it uses a HashTable internally...

Comment: he meant GetHashCode of the compared object.

Comment: You'll be comparing `Task` items, not `TaskComparer` items (which you only have one of anyway).  Task needs a GetHashCode, not TaskComparer.

Comment: What if the id or name are null?  Computing a hash should not crash.

Answer (score 2):

```
 var uniqueTasks = allTasks.Select(t=>t.TypeName).Distinct().ToList();
```