# struggling with linq query for distinct results

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, object

I have a list of invoice line objects.

I want to show a list of unique invoices, so that later I can show the invoice lines for the selected distinct invoice.

```
    List<Invoice> returnInvoices = (List<Invoice>)Session["Invoices"];
    var uniqueInvoices = from i in returnInvoices
                           select new
                           {
                               i.InvoiceNo,
                               i.InvoiceDate,
                               i.OrderNo,
                               i.CustomerPO,
                           };
    GridView3.DataSource = uniqueInvoices;
    GridView3.DataBind();
```

How to I return unique results on `InvoiceNo` ? I'm really struggling to get my head around this :(

Comment: tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328917/linq-distinct-query ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Really, you shouldn't be worrying about getting distinct invoices out of your session variable - you should be worrying about why there are duplicates in there in the first place. At what point are you adding an invoice to the session variable without checking if there's one there already?

That said, you can pick one invoice per ID as follows:

```
var nonUniqueInvoices = from i in returnInvoices
                       select new
                       {
                           i.InvoiceNo,
                           i.InvoiceDate,
                           i.OrderNo,
                           i.CustomerPO,
                       }; // as before
var uniqueInvoices = nonUniqueInvoices
    .GroupBy(i => i.InvoiceNo)
    .Select(g => g.First());
GridView3.Datasource = uniqueInvoices; // as before
```

This will just select the *first* invoice per ID it finds in the list; this may not be the most up-to-date duplicate.

---

If you *only* need the IDs, not one-item-per-ID, you can just use

```
var uniqueInvoiceIDs = returnInvoices.Select(i => i.InvoiceNo).Distinct();
```

which should be much more efficient.

Comment: Thanks I will give this a go!
I'm not worried about why there are duplicates, because there are supposed to be duplicates. It's not a list of invoices, it's a list of invoice lines. One invoice may contain 5 parts and each part has its own line. When the invoice is selected the page will then show  each part, hence why I only need distinct invoice numbers to show first off. Unfortunately I have no control over how the information is provided to me so I have to work with it.

Comment: @Stuart OK, that seems reasonable. I'll add an alternative in case you only need the IDs, not "a lnie for each ID".

Comment: This works perfect! thanks for the help :) +1 and marked as answer!

Answer (score 0):

Build a custom of `EqualityComparer<Invoice>` for [`Enumerable.Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx):

```
public class InvoiceComparer : IEqualityComparer<Invoice>
{
    public bool Equals(Invoice x, Invoice y)
    {
        if (x == null || y == null) return false;
        return x.InvoiceNo == y.InvoiceNo;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Invoice obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return int.MinValue;

        return obj.InvoiceNo.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then you can get the result by using `Distinct` with the custom comparer:

```
List<Invoice> invoices = (List<Invoice>)Session["Invoices"];
IEnumerable<Invoice> uniqueInvoices = invoices.Distinct(new InvoiceComparer());
```