# Get distinct records with latest effective date, sorted by number

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I need to get all distinct records from an Item table with the latest DateEffective, where DateDeleted is null and sorted by ItemNumber.

```
Id     ItemNumber     Name     Price     DateEffective     DateDeleted
 1           1001      Cat         1        2014-02-14            null
 2           1002      Dog         3        2014-02-14            null
 3           1001      Cat         2        2014-02-20            null
```

Until now, I've fetched all non-deleted records, but since introducing ItemNumber, and thereby possible duplicates, I can't do that anymore.

```
context.Items.Where(i => i.DateDeleted == null).ToList();
```

The query should return the second and third record, but not the first, since it's an older version of the third record.

Also, I've read suggestions about putting temporal data in a separate table. What would be the benefit of doing so, compared to the above example? In this case, Name, Price and DateEffective would be candidates for a temporal table.

Thank you.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328917/linq-distinct-query

Answer (score 3):

This would work

```
context.Items.Where(i => i.DateDeleted == null)
       .GroupBy(x => x.ItemNumber)
       .Select(g => g.First(x => x.DateEffective == g.Max(y => y.DateEffective))
       .OrderBy(x => x.ItemNumber)
       .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get the following error:

"The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead."

Comment: @Lahey okey then try FirstOrDefault instead of First

Comment: I did, but I got the following inner exception:

"{"APPLY joins are not supported"}"